# How can I extend motherboard W-Fi/Bluetooth? (re: two antenna jacks; do I need two extensions?)

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna

I have a server rack with a bunch of different equipment including one server that has a WiFi/Bluetooth card.  (I need the bluetooth capability, but not WiFi).

The signal inside the rack is probably terrible so I'd like to use an extension (20ft) to place the antenna in a better location.

However, most WiFi/Bluetooth cards have two separate antenna jacks.  I'm not sure the purpose because I took apart the included antenna and it had two PCB-trace antennas that looked exactly the same so I don't think they are tuned for different frequencies).

My goal is to extend the bluetooth signal (2.4 GHz).

Can I use RP-SMA adapters and extend over RG6 coaxial cable?

Do I need to connect both RP-SMA jacks on the WiFi/Bluetooth card?  If so, can I use a simple Y-splitter to connect them to a signal extension cable?

Comment: probably depends on the "card" - without knowing the make/model it's a guess which one to use - I know my one the connectors are labeled main and aux, and the aux is used for bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

Easiest might be to buy an external USB Bluetooth adapter such as [this for US$15](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09MZ8715D), which has an external antenna, *and connect it via a short USB extension cord*, so that it is farther away from the electrically noisy rack and closer to the device with which it is shared.

BTW, I used that technique for a 3G wireless modem, i.e., adding an extension and moving the device to different locations, while monitoring reception, and got *much* better signal quality.